# Handling FileNotFound when streaming audio files

Tags: jquery, .net, html5-audio

I am trying to use .net as a mediation service for streaming audio from another server.

eg: externalserver.com/?u=xxx&p=xxx&id=123

My html audio tag src has url myserver.com/?id=123

In this, I am reading the response stream in byte buffers and forwarding it to audio tag.

But in some cases, the external server returns result like 'File is not found. Or incorrect formatting'.

The **onerror** eventlistener is not getting triggered when I stream the server result as is. I was wondering if there is something like onplayerror.

Basically, I want to notify the user if the stream returns any plaintext errors and is not an audio stream. I am unable to use plaintext checks as the stream is loaded internally by audio element through it's src.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how are you using `<audio>` tag in your html, one solution would be to add div

```
<div id="player">click to play</div>

<audio preload="none" controls>
    <source id="wav" src="http://example.com/404.wav" />
</audio>
```

then add event handlers

```
("#player").on("click", function () {
    try {
        $('audio')[0].play();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error");
    }
});

$("audio").on("error", function (e) {
        console.log("Error");
    });

$("#wav").on("error", function (e) {
        console.log("Error");
    });
```

this should handle any error not only 404.